# Array representation in a specific way of table format in codeIgniter view file?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, html-table, dompdf

I have an array in the below format. This array had around 100 elements in same format. I want to represent the whole array in a specific format of table using `DOMPDF` library using codeIgniter.

```
result = Array(
              [0] => Array (
                     ['brand'] => x,
                     ['product'] =>p1,
                     ['language']=>English,
                    );
              [1] => Array (
                     ['brand'] => x,
                     ['product'] =>p2,
                     ['language']=>English,
                    );
              );
```

I like to represent them in the below format using `<table>` tags in `html`.

```
  Brand          x             y
  Product        p1            p2
  Language       English       English
```

I am looking for ideas. I have those kind of array elements not 2 more than 100. I want to loop them.

So after request below i am going to post my code.

```
<?php foreach($result as $res)

 {
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Brand</td>
        <td><?php echo $res['brand'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Product</td>
        <td><?php echo $res['product'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Language/td>
        <td><?php echo $res['language'] ?></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
}
```

This will give you output for one product like this.
      Brand          x
      Product        p1
      Language       English

How I can do loop for other products to get output of how I want above?

Note: not only 3 fields in each array element. I have more than 30 fields. May be you think I am going this way only because of print able area in the PDF page.

Comment: I don't know exactly what it is. But i want to represent them in that format. I can able to do it for first element. But after that how can i show next one using table tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Vengat, following coding are working Good. Try This One...

```
<?php
$result = Array(
              0 => Array (
                     'brand' => 'x',
                     'product' =>'p1',
                     'language'=>'English',
                    ),
              1 => Array (
                     'brand'=> 'y',
                     'product' =>'p2',
                     'language'=>'English',
                    )
              );


    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr><td>Brand</td>';
    foreach($result as $res)
    {
        echo "<td>".$res['brand']."</td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>Product</td>';
    foreach($result as $res)
    {
        echo "<td>".$res['product']."</td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>Language</td>';
    foreach($result as $res)
    {
        echo "<td>".$res['language']."</td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';   
    echo '</table>';

?>
```

Output is:

```
Brand   x   y
Product p1  p2
Language    English English
```

Use css for alignment.

Comment: @karSHo  i thought also this only. I will accept it as answer once after i tried.

Answer (score 5):

Use `foreach` for getting each array from result array. and use `multiple array (row[ ][ ])` with `key`. you can print `<tr><td>` all are in `echo`.

Comment: can you post some example code using table tags. Because i think it's not possible i am following the same way in my view files.

Comment: @Shoshan check out edit code in question. If your idea is not how i showed please comment it.